# How do I access specific arrays?

Tags: python

```
for amount in number:
    data = [amount.span.text]
    print(data)

['663,794 ']
['12,968']
['577,754']
```

How can I access the first array?
I tried using [0] but it just gives me the first number of the last array

Comment: Each of these `list`S has but one value: a `str`, this is why `data[0]` gives you only the first character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My preferred way of doing it is to start with an empty list to which you append each item and are therefore able to refer to each one using it's index

```
empty_list = []

for amount in number:
    data = [amount.span.text]
    empty_list.append(data)

print(empty_list[0])
```